# Can this code lead to deadlock?

Tags: c#, locking

I'm reviewing a piece of code I wrote some time ago, now I was wondering if the nested lock on the same variable can lead to a deadlock

```
lock (DealLock)
{
     if (dealmapping.ContainsKey(deal.Deal.Id))
     {
        var oldItem = dealmapping[deal.Deal.Id];

        var index = Deals.FindIndex(x => x.Id == deal.Deal.Id);

        if (index > -1)
            if (deal.Status == DealStatus.Updated)
            {
                  Deals[index].PopulateWith(deal);

                  Deals[index].IsChanged = true;


            }
            else
            {
                  Deals.Remove(Deals.First(x => x.Id == deal.Deal.Id));
            }

            lock (DealLock) //This one
            {
                   dealmapping = Deals.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, y => y);
            }
}
```

Is the inner lock useless/incorrect since I'm just lock before?

Thanks in adavance

## UPDATE #1

After having read post, the prosposed solution would be

```
if (dealmapping.ContainsKey(deal.Deal.Id))
{
   var oldItem = dealmapping[deal.Deal.Id];

   var index = Deals.FindIndex(x => x.Id == deal.Deal.Id);

   if (index > -1)
   {
       lock (DealLock)
       {
            if (deal.Status == DealStatus.Updated)
            {
               Deals[index].PopulateWith(deal);

               Deals[index].IsChanged = true;

            }
            else
            {
               Deals.Remove(Deals.First(x => x.Id == deal.Deal.Id));
            }

            dealmapping = Deals.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, y => y);
     }
   }
}
```

## UPDATE 2

Excuse me, I've found another piece of code that makes use of locks and I think here there're more issues than before

```
  private object isRefreshingLock = new object();

    public void Refresh()
    {
        if (!IsVisible) return;

        lock (isRefreshingLock)
        {
            dispatcherService.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (ScrollViewer != null)
                {
                    HorizontalScrollViewOffset = ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
                    VerticalScrollViewOffset = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
                }

                lock (_queueLock)
                {
                    while (queue.Count > 0)
                        try
                        {
                            var deal = queue.Dequeue();

                            Log.Verbose($"Deal base - Dequeued {deal.Deal.Id} from deal queue");
                            if (deal.Status == DealStatus.New && !dealmapping.ContainsKey(deal.Deal.Id))
                            {
                                lock (DealLock)
                                {
                                    Deals.Add(deal.Deal);
                                    dealmapping = Deals.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, y => y);
                                }

                                Log.Verbose($"Deal base - Added {deal.Deal.Id} to deals");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lock (DealLock)
                                {
                                    if (dealmapping.ContainsKey(deal.Deal.Id))
                                    {
                                        var oldItem = dealmapping[deal.Deal.Id];

                                        var index = Deals.FindIndex(x => x.Id == deal.Deal.Id);

                                        if (index > -1)
                                            if (deal.Status == DealStatus.Updated)
                                            {
                                                Deals[index].PopulateWith(deal.Deal);

                                                Deals[index].IsChanged = true;

                                                Log.Verbose($"Deal base - Updated {deal.Deal.Id} inside deals");
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Deals.Remove(Deals.First(x => x.Id == deal.Deal.Id));
                                            }

                                        dealmapping = Deals.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, y => y);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if (GridView.GroupDescriptors.Any())
                                GridView.GroupDescriptors.Reset();

                            Log.Verbose($"Deal base - Updated lookup table with deal {deal.Deal.Id}");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Log.Error(ex, "");
                        }
                }


            });
        }
    }
```

Does it make sense to lock then call the dispatcher or it's better to set it inside the action passed to the disclaimer? the queue lock is used since I'm using a custom queue that only contains the latest item if there're two elements with the same ID

Thanks again

Comment: your inner code is already in the lock so you don't need another one inside i think

Comment: It is indeed useless.

Comment: The inner lock is unnecessary because it locks the same object which you already have a lock on. But because of this a deadlock is also not possible. Therefore you need to have a lock on two different objects.

Comment: Your code locking can start from `if (index > -1)`, since that's when you modify object else you are just reading and that would be sufficient just once, inside a lock there cannot be another thread, though your code is not deadlock since same thread has the lock on object, it will not wait to acquire it again

Comment: @MrinalKamboj check my update please

Comment: Why concatenated locks, this could be dangerous and can lead to deadlock, check answer underneath

Answer (score 2):

Yes the inner lock is redundant since you try to lock the same object in the same thread. The object is already locked by the thread and the code continues.

Here no deadlock is possible since another thread that runs through the same code already stops at the outer lock and waits for it being released. A deadlock would be possible if you lock another object in the inner lock and another thread does it vice versa. E.g:

Thread 1:

```
lock(object1) {
    // do something 
    lock (object2) {
      // ...
    }

}
```

Thread 2:

```
lock(object2) {  // happens exactly while thread 1 is in "do something"
    //
    lock (object1) {
      // ...
    }

}
```

Now each thread is waiting for the other thread to release the lock.